# Testing incorrect string when using typed literal

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have the function

```
function main(input: 'bat' | 'spider' = 'bat') {
    switch (input) {
        case 'bat':
            return "batman";
        case 'spider':
            return "spiderman";
        default:
            throw new Error('Unknown input type');
    }
}
```

I am unable to test passing a wrong param as I will get a compiler error.

```
Argument of type 'bannana' is not assignable to parameter of type '"bat" | "man" | undefined'.ts(2345)
```

Test is:

```
describe('throws error', () => {
    it('when invalid input is passed', () => {
        const result = main('bannana'); <--- Type error
        expect(result).toThrowError();
    });
});
```

Comment: Unit test is meant to test runtime behavior. TS works in the design time phase. They're basically two different stages and aren't supposed to work together. Disable ts check behavior in the unit test file, or you can write unit test entirely in js.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
// @ts-expect-error
const result = main('bannana');
```